# Adobe Flash on Linux

Tags: flash, adobe

I cannot watch a video stream because the site says I need Adobe Flash 11.8.0. My version is 11.2.202. (This is a recently acquired used computer formerly with Windows and now with Linux. I am not a tech person - I'm an end user. So be kind, please!!)

I went to the Adobe site and it stated I had the latest version for Linux. I went to the Adobe site directed by the video provider (Comcast) and I saw a statement that Adobe is not providing upgrades for Linux beyond 11.2 any longer.

I tried downloading a version from the Adobe site and the readme.txt told me to unpack the tar.gz file. On your Q&A site, it says not to use a tar.gz file.

Can anyone direct me in end-user language (who knows nothing about Linux) what I need to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in this case is to use Google Chrome. It has the latest Adobe Flash built-in.

Comment: It is not completely true. It is not Adobe Flash, but Pepper Flash, isn't it?

Comment: @Jakuje: While Pepper Flash is maintained by Google it's still developed by Adobe.